# Sign in using Google

Tags: jmeter

My project had implemented google sign in with company name as domain.
I need to sign in to get idtoken send by Google on successful authentication.

I tried all searching but still not able to get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about this [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/) you basically need to obtain the [Bearer token](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer.html) and add it to your requests using [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager)

As JMeter cannot execute JavaScript you have the following options:

1. Use hard-coded token which you can get from the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/)
2. Obtain the token dynamically using a real browser with [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler)
3. Obtain the token programmatically using [Google API Client libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/) from the [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

Comment: I had used WebDriver Sampler and able to logged in , now how can i get token which I need.?